# How can I disable 'sent' event.type when using a custom http request in Angular?

Tags: angular, httprequest

When I use a not-pre-defined http request in Angular (7), I got response 2 times in my subscribe body, but if I use a pre-define http request like GET, there is only 1 response.

**A custom request (SEARCH) in service:**

```
  searchFileByCategory(categories: Array<string>): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.request(new HttpRequest('SEARCH', ENDPOINTS.SEARCH_FILE_BY_CATEGORY, {categories: categories}));
  }
```

**In component:**

```
  refreshTable(): void {
    this.backEndService.searchFileByCategory(this.categories).subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event);
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
        this.files = event.body.data;
      }
    });
  }
```

*1st event log:*

```
{type: 0}
```

*2nd event log:*

```
{body: {data: {…}}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: 4
url: "http://localhost/..."}
```

As you can see I have to check (**event.type === HttpEventType.Response**) because **event.body.data** doesn't exist in the 1st response.

HttpEventType enum in node_modules@angular\common\http\src\response.d.ts:

```
export declare enum HttpEventType {
    /**
     * The request was sent out over the wire.
     */
    Sent = 0,
    /**
     * An upload progress event was received.
     */
    UploadProgress = 1,
    /**
     * The response status code and headers were received.
     */
    ResponseHeader = 2,
    /**
     * A download progress event was received.
     */
    DownloadProgress = 3,
    /**
     * The full response including the body was received.
     */
    Response = 4,
    /**
     * A custom event from an interceptor or a backend.
     */
    User = 5
}
```

I have understood what the 1st response is. But I don't understand the reason why GET does not have the same.

**A GET request in service:**

```
  getZipCodes(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(ENDPOINTS.GET_ZIP_CODES);
  }
```

**In component:**

```
  refreshZipCodes(): void {
    this.backEndService.getZipCodes().subscribe(response => this.zipCodes = response.data)
  }
```

Here there is no need for checking (event.type === HttpEventType.Response). Why?

My final purpose is to get rid of checking (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) every time when I call a custom http request. How can I do it?

Comment: from angular source  `events$.filter((event: HttpEvent<any>) => event instanceof HttpResponse));`, so you can do the same filtering to to remove type=0 event

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a custom get request.

Comment: @Ankesh One of the reasons: GET does not have body and the criterias of the searching procedure is more complex than query params can provide.

Comment: @ABOS you were right: it works.

Comment: @ABOS thanks.................:)

Answer (score 0):

@ABOS's answer under the post looks good, it works:

```
  searchLastContentByCategory(category: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.request(new HttpRequest('SEARCH', ENDPOINTS.SEARCH_LAST_CONTENT_BY_CATEGORY, {category: category}))
      .pipe(filter((event: HttpEvent<any>) => event instanceof HttpResponse));
  }
```